# How can I exclude Recurring Activities Series records from a trigger?

Tags: trigger, activities

We have a code that prevents us from closing a project if there are still open activities.

The trouble is that it picks up the "Not Started" Status update on the Recurring Tasks Series, even when the series has ended (end date has passed).  The Status of the actual Recurring Series record can't be updated:
[image]

The code is:

```
public static void checkIncompleteTask(List<amc__Project__c> newList, Map<Id, amc__Project__c> oldMap) {

        List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN: newList AND Status != 'Completed'];
```

Can anyone assist in excluding Recurring Series records from this?  It doesn't appear as a separate RT, and isn't a reportable activity in itself.

Cheers, Nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have one field on Task `IsRecurrence` which you can use here.

Add this parameter in your query

```
IsRecurrence = false
```

So it will exclude all the Recurring Series records.

Comment: Thanks so much Tushar!!  I'll pass that on to my internal team to look at updating the code :)